# Relayjs fragment not available on child container, even though the query was successful

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I have a parent container that looks like this:

```
const HomeContainer =  Relay.createContainer(HomeClass, {
    initialVariables: {
        first: 66,
        userIdAndCookie: {
            id: "",
            cookie: ""
        },
        filterBy: {subTypes: ["Event","Social Media Photography"]}
    },

    fragments: {
        allUsersFragment: ($params) => Relay.QL`
            fragment on AllUsers {
                ${UserBoxList.getFragment('allUsersFragment', $params)}
            }
        `,
    }
}
```

And a nested container that looks like this:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(UserBoxList, {
    initialVariables: {
        first: 600,
        filterBy: null
    },

    fragments: {
        allUsersFragment: ({$first, $filterBy}) => Relay.QL`
            fragment on AllUsers {
                allUsersField(first: $first, filterBy: $filterBy) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            id,
                            name,
                            surname,
                            businessName,
                            rating,
                            supplierType,
                            locationNames,
                            locationZips
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `
    }
});
```

The HomeContainer correctly passes the parameters to the UserBoxList, and when I look at the network tab I correctly receive all the data from the query that is done with the correct parameters. However, when I do this:

```
const users = this.props.allUsersFragment.allUsersField.edges.map(user => {
    if(user.node.supplierType === this.props.selectedSupplierType) {
        return (
            <UserBox
                usernode={user.node}
                key={user.node.id}
                showCreateTaskRequestBox={this.props.showCreateTaskRequestBox}
            />
        )
    }
});
```

in my UserBoxList, allUsersField is undefined. When I look at `this.props.allUsersFragment`, I see this:

```
Object {__dataID__: "client:-222288344603", __status__: 4}
```

but no data! Even though I can see the data in my network tab:

```
{data: {,…}}
data
:
{,…}
allUsersQuery
:
{_allUsersField1YSY3b: {edges: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…],…}}
_allUsersField1YSY3b
:
{edges: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…],…}
edges
:
[{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]
pageInfo
:
{hasNextPage: true, hasPreviousPage: false}
```

My question is, am I missing something obvious? Or is this a bug?

**EDIT**

If I remove the variable passing from Home -> UserBoxList, and just use the
`initialVariables` in UserBoxList, it works just fine.

At the time of initial render, UserBoxList relay variables are not the ones I passed from Home, they are the ones from `initialVariables` in the UserBoxList container, but the only query actually being made is made with the correct paramters from the Home container

**EDIT2**

Apparently there is also an issue on github regarding the same problem:

https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1101

Answer (score 0):

This answer, by Joseph Savona, worked for me:

Be sure to pass any overridden variables down in props, so `<Child customerId={this.props.relay.variables.customerId} ... />`.